# How do I know If IOS App in background using faye server

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ios5, faye

I have been implementing `Faye` for our `IOS` chat application. Since I don’t know much about the `IOS` side, I am little bit confused. Every thing works fine but my client asks me to check if `IOS` app has received the push message but as far as `Faye` is concerned it only checks `/meta/disconnect` and `/meta/unsubscribe` channel for client deactivation but how do i know that `IOS` app goes to background because than I have to send msg through `APNS`. But my client doesn’t want to hit Rails API to tell browser about the APP Status. Little bit confused please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can know your app goes in background when this method from your ApplicationDelegate is called :

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
```

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

You can also listen for the UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification event from any controller :

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(appHasGoneInBackground:)
                                             name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification
                                           object:nil];
```

Here is a thread that covers this subject :

[Use of background/foreground methods in AppDelegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4846822/iphone-use-of-background-foreground-methods-in-appdelegate)