# ios updateDisplay on a timer

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimer, viewdidload, uiapplicationdelegate

I've got a somewhat complicated iOS user interface, where I need to reload a particular cell of a UICollectionView every second to show time (kind of like a complicated stopwatch), I also need to do a few other things every second in this call.

#### Part 1 of question

---

My question is what is the best practice for doing this *type* of problem?

**Option 1** (use recursive call)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [self runUpdateDisplayLoop];
}
- (void)runUpdateDisplayLoop
{
   //do stuff (reload cell, etc)
       
   //Recurissively Call Every Second
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        
        [self performSelector:@selector(runUpdateDisplayLoop) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
        
    });
}
```

**Option 2** (use NSTimer)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   NSTimer *updateDisplayTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                              target:self 
                                            selector:@selector(runUpdateDisplayLoop:) 
                                            userInfo:nil 
                                             repeats:YES];
}

- (void)updateDisplayLoop:(NSTimer *) theTimer
{
 //do stuff (reload cell, etc)
}
```

**Part 2 of Question**

---

In either case, what is the best place to initiate and terminate these loops?

If I put them in ViewDidLoad they will continue being called even when I've navigated away from the relevant view, i'd rather only have the loop running when it needs to be. On the other hand, the loop must be running every time the view is displayed (even when the view has been dismissed in all variety of ways - app dismissed and reopened, phone call interruption, etc). In regards to app lifecycle, i'm targeting iOS 5 and iOS 6.

I'm guessing there is a solution involving "viewWillAppear" and "viewWillDisappear", but i'm leery of getting into situations where one or the other isn't called. I also don't want to spawn multiple loops by making any false assumptions.

Comment: The timer will give you more accurate 1 second interval.  The timer is also easier to stop when you close anything so that you don't crash by trying to call a function on a non-existant `self`.  Given the option I would not go recursive.

Comment: Is there a reason the NSTimer is more "accurate"? I haven't looked into it, but my assumption was that at some point, the performSelector with day would use the same mechanism as an NSTimer.

Comment: It would be more accurate because with the recursive you are running a bunch of code that takes time, then setting a single timer for one more second (more than the code excecution time).  The NSTimer fors off every second (unless it doesn't have enought CPU time in which case it will just "break frames" and skip a call here and there).  This is all my experience, I have no documentation to back any of this up.

Comment: Having ran both implementations, it does appear that NSTimer is more accurate. By about an order of magnitude. Where the recursive call occurs every second, it's typically off by about .01-.02 seconds each time. The NSTimer looks to only be off by .001 and only sometimes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For **Part 1**

I recommend using a timer. The main reason is so you can stop the process by invalidating the timer. Using performSelector you can achieve something similar but I wouldn't go that route. To each their own.

For **Part 2**

You do want to use `viewWillAppear` (or `viewDidAppear`) and `viewDidDisappear` (or `viewWillDisappear`). Setup the timer on appear and tear it down on disappear.

Check out [RespondingtoDisplay-Notifications](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/RespondingtoDisplay-Notifications/RespondingtoDisplay-Notifications.html)

Hope that sheds a light on things and addresses your "but i'm leery of getting into situations where one or the other isn't called." concern

Comment: Yeah, this does help. And this is a great answer. I'm definitely leaning towards the NSTimer approach. I'm still having issues using viewDidAppear and viewDidDisappear. viewDidAppear is not called when the app opens after having been dismissed. Is that a concern? or will the timer just still be running from the previous viewDidAppear call? And I can rely on that.

Comment: Your viewcontroller should monitor when it goes into the background. Here is a way to approach this. http://stackoverflow.com/a/7341053/1539045

Answer (score 1):

While `NSTimer` will kind of work, it's not really made for creating stop watches or the like. You can't rely on it firing every second, so you'll still need to use a `NSDate` object and something like `timeIntervalSinceDate` to calculate the value to display for the timer each time it fires. That way, your stop watch can catch up if it should happen to not fire for one or more seconds.

NSTimer events are processed by the main run loop, and if the main run loop is busy, the events aren't fired.

I like the background thread idea better. However, you don't need the recursion to make it work.

Simply create a custom Timer class with a start, calcTime, (and perhaps stop, reset, and resume). When you call start, the object should simply get the current date/time (NSDate) and store it. When you call calcTime, simply get the current date/time again, calculate the time elapsed using `timeIntervalSinceDate`, and either return the value or set properties that you can read.

In a background thread, simply keep calling the `calcTime` method and update the UI via `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_que)()`, then sleep for maybe 100 milliseconds between calls. You can check a Boolean global variable to see if you should keep running.

A background thread still may get bogged down if the processor is pegged, however, that's less likely to happen than the main run loop being busy, which is responsible for so much.

I've created a stop watch app, and this is the method I used, after deciding NSTimer wasn't viable.

Comment: Yes, this is really good information. I'm definitely not using NSTimer to track the actual time. I'm tracking all of the times using NSDate objects. I'm only using this NSTimer to fire the display update loop.